# Using knockoutjs to data-bind list data into bxslider

Tags: sharepoint, data-binding, knockout.js, bxslider

I have managed to get the code to display list data which is driven from a sharepoint list. The list only contains one column in each row item which is called Title. I need to display the titles through the bxslider, one item per slide.

**Usual bxslider html**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**My html implementing data-bind**

```
<ul class="bxslider" data-bind="foreach: items">
  <li data-bind="text: Title"></li>
</ul>
```

For some reason the 'Titles' are all being generated in one li tag, rather than creating an li tag for each item in the list.
If anyone has come across this problem before or have any advice or suggestions it would be very much appreciated.

**View Model**

```
var items = ko.observable(); 
jQuery(document).ready(function () {   
     jQuery.getJSON( "ListURLHERE", {}, dataCallBack   
     );  
ko.applyBindings(); 
});  
function dataCallBack(data) { 
    items(data.d.results); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe try the `html` binding instead of the `text` binding

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately using 'html' binding gives the same result as using 'text' binding in this case.

Comment: Seems to [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/CXpcm/1/). Can you share more details or reproduce the problem in the demo link?

Comment: Can you post your viewModel?

Comment: I updated GôTô's jsfiddle here and it worked correctly [jsfiddle.net/CXpcm/9/. But it isnt working when grabbing from a SharePoint list. The data is brought back but all in one li. I have updated the post to display the view model above.

Comment: I have found the answer to the problem!

I was initiating the bxslider function before the knockout js code. I had to implement the bxslider function into the dataCallBack function and it worked.

    `function dataCallBack(data) {
     News(data.d.results);
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    });
    }`

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to the problem!

I was initiating the bxslider function before the knockout js code. I had to implement the bxslider function into the dataCallBack function and it worked.

```
function dataCallBack(data) {
    News(data.d.results);
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
}
```

Thanks for your help everyone!